# Could not find the correct Provider<VoteState> above this

Tags: flutter

I was trying to create a voting app. I have encountered an error. The error is ***Could not find the correct Provider above this***. 
Here's a link to projects GitHub:

Answer (score 0):

You can move `MultiProvider` setting from `FirstPage` to `main()`

```
void main() => runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => VoteState(),
      )
    ], child: MyApp()));
```

FirstPage

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
     resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

working demo

[image]

Comment: thanks for helping me out, but upon running the app only question is displayed but not the options. can you look into it and help me out
?

Comment: your code only has one item. so for loop only show one item. In your VoteOptions, you do not have code to show options. you only display voteTitle